# CDI constructor injection of a request scoped object

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi

Is it possible to inject a request scoped CDI component into a application scoped CDI component via construction injection? The point is that, when the application scoped object is instantiated, the request scoped object might not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're free to do this, you get a proxy injected that obtains/creates the appropriate instance when you call a business method on it.

Comment: So, when the constructor is called, the CDI runtime passes a proxy to the bean? And when I call some method on the proxy, it takes care of getting the real object?